# How to read files from a folder and use them in an arrary

Tags: java, arrays, file

I am Trying to read all the files in a folder and create an arrary with the data.
I know there may be other topics with this but i am having trouble searching For the answer.

Heres the code i am using

```
import java.io.File;

public class test3 {
public static void main( String [] args ) {
    File actual = new File("."); //replace . with file path
    int x = 1;
    for( File f : actual.listFiles()){
        System.out.println( x + ". " + f.getName() );
        x++;
    }
}}
```

Thanks

Comment: Can you please clarify?  What exactly is wrong?  What do you expect to happen?  I'm confused when you say "search", because there's no evidence of searching in your code.  What you are looking for?  File names?  Content?  Your question is unclear.

Comment: Sorry i ment serching for answers on this question i will edit thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's an [example](http://www.exampledepot.com/egs/java.io/readlinesfromfile.html) that shows how to read from a file.

Inside that loop you have to open the file, read its contents, and add it to another array or List.  Then you can search through the contents of each one.